# Which one to use - executeUpate or list - to insert and update and select?

Tags: java, hibernate, stored-procedures

I've written a stored procedure with the following sql statements

1. insert a row in table a
2. update a row in table b
3. insert a row in error table
4. select query to list the number of records in the error table

Can i use query.list() ? Will it does all the inserts, updates and returns the list properly?

I think we cannot use query.executeUpdate() as it returns only number of rows updated or inserted at last sql statement.

Thanks in advance,
Kathir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/how-to-call-store-procedure-in-hibernate/

See above link for sample of how to call stored procedures with hibernate

if you are using spring, you can call stored procedures via Spring JdbcTemplate as well.

Comment: I cannot use both..I can use only one...Since all these statements are going to be present in a "Single Stored Procedure"..Please suggest me whether i can use query.list() ?

Comment: I'm using hibernate framework and using hibernate class Query and methods executeUpdate() or list(). calling the stored procedure via namedQuery method.

Comment: My question is not how to call the stored procedure but to know can i use the query.list() for the above queries which exist under a single stored procedure.

Comment: Yes, you can. All stored procedures needs to return a resultset. Why not try and see. The link already shows examples calling list method.

Answer (score 1):

If it is stored procedure you can use do like this

```
 try
   {
      con  = connectionPool.getConnection();
      proc = con.prepareCall("{ call set_death_age(?, ?) }");
      proc.setString(1, dyingBard.getName());
      proc.setInt(2, age);
      proc.execute();
   }
      catch (SQLException e) {}
```

Comment: The stored procedure cannot be changed. I need to use the stored procedure. My question what will be the impact if i use query.list() in the above case?

Comment: My question is not how to call the stored procedure but to know can i use the query.list() for the above queries which exist under a single stored procedure.